# Sweet-alert-rails-confirm with rails submit button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sweetalert

I just installed [sweet-alert-rails-confirm](https://github.com/mois3x/sweet-alert-rails-confirm) on my rails application, and it worked fine when using the `data-confirm` attribute with `link_to`, but when I added the `data-confirm` attribute to a form submit button it still shows the old javascript confirm prompt, like the following:

```
<%= f.submit "#{@projeto.new_record? ? 'Cadastrar' : 'Atualizar'} #{f.object.e_proposta? ? 'proposta' : 'projeto' }", data: { confirm: 'Tem certeza?' }   if current_user.administrador_do_perfil?(perfil)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, as I've never used that gem before, but instead of the `f.submit`, try adding simple button element with the `data-confirm` element.

Comment: Didn't work, still get the ugly javascript confirm popup

Comment: Bueller? Bueller? Bueller?